# Javascript, poner nombre de propiedad a un objeto desde el contenido de una variable

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objeto

Buen dia, una pregunta , tengo una variable, ejemplo: let mes='Enero'  pero quiero que el CONTENIDO de esa variable (Enero) sea el NOMBRE de una propiedad de un objeto, digamos este es el objeto

```
  const pagoResumen = {
  alumnoNombre: nombre,
  ValorDeMes= true,
}
```

En la segunda propiedad quiero que el nombre de la propiedad sea el valor de la variable mes, en este caso Enero ¿se puede?

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es: **¿se puede?**, la respuesta es: **Si**. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta para que sea más específica, indicando lo que hayas intentado, mostrando los errores y el resultado esperado. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, tendré en cuenta lo que comentas para las siguientes consultas

Answer (score 3):

Para hacerlo sería de la siguiente manera:

```
const mes = "Enero"
const obj = {}
obj[mes] = true // {Enero: true}
```

La notación de corchetes se suele usar cuando se necesita hacer justamente eso que necesitas de asignar dinamicamente claves a un objeto

Te dejo un link en donde se detallada muy bien sobre este tema.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos

Comment: Mil gracias! me sirvio